# How do I calculate TF-IDF of a query?

Tags: search, computer-science, tf-idf, data-retrieval

How do I calculate `tf-idf` for a query? I understand how to calculate tf-idf for a set of documents with following definitions:

> **tf** = occurances in document/ total words in document
>
> **idf** = log(#documents / #documents where term occurs

But I don't understand how that correlates to queries.

**For example**, I read [a resource](https://janav.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity/) that stated the values of a query "`life learning`"

> life | tf = .5 | idf =    1.405507153 | tf_idf = 0.702753576
>   learning | tf = .5 | idf =    1.405507153 | tf_idf = 0.702753576

The `tf` values I understand, each term appears only once out of the two possible terms, thus 1/2, But I have no idea where the `idf` comes from.
I would think that #documents = 1 and occurrence = 1, log(1) = 0, so `idf` would be 0, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is it based on whatever documents you're using? How do you calculate tf-idf for a query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only tf(life) depends on the query itself. However, the idf of a query depends on the background documents, so idf(life) = 1+ ln(3/2) ~= 1.405507153. 
That is why tf-idf is defined as multiplying a local component (term frequency) with a global component (inverse document frequency).

Comment: How do i calculate idf based on background documents? Eg: query="british chunnel impact", then tf would be 1/3 but will idf remain 1+log(3/2)~=1.405507153 or will it change?

Answer (score 7):

Assume your query is **best car insurance**, your total vocabulary contains **car, best, auto, insurance** and you have `N=1,000,000` documents. So your query is something like below:

[image]

And one of your document could be:

[image]

Now calculate *cosine similarity* between `TF-IDF` of your `Query` and `Document`.

Comment: I find this example really confusing. I know this is taken from Stanford lecture notes and thus it should be valid but isn't idf made to be part of the "document part" like @hypnoticpoisons stated in his answer? From this example it looks like it's part of a "query part" which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

Even if this question is marked as answered. I don't feel like it was fully answered.
So if maybe anyone will need this in the future:

> But I have no idea where the idf comes from.

In this example: [Project 3, part 2: Searching using TF-IDF](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/17au/project3/project3-2.html)
It is presented how to compute the cosine similarity between a query and a set of documents.

As [@hypnoticpoisons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6728986/hypnoticpoisons) stated the IDF is a a global component, so the IDF of a word will be the same for each document:

> Note: technically, we are treating the query as if it were a new document. However, you should not recompute the IDF values: just use the ones you computed earlier.